# how to send the same data twice using android wear DataApi?

Tags: android, android-studio, listener, wear-os, sendmessage

For example if we have media player and we want to press next button twice and send this action every time to mobile using DataApi.

Problem is that DataApi uses onDataChange which will send data only when Data has changed.

Is there any other options to get my example working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example if we have media player and we want to press next button
>   twice and send this action every time to mobile using DataApi.
>
> Problem is that DataApi uses onDataChange which will send data only
>   when Data has changed

That's the expected behaviour and this done for saving resources. If you want to force this behaviour you can add the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the payload (E.g. to DataMap) in order to cheat the system and send the payload again.

Edit:

For sending messages you should use the [MessageApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi)

Comment: It worked thanks. But is there any better way for sending  an action like "next" in AndroidWear. It looks like that Datapi is not a good choice.

Comment: if the payload does not exceed the maximum allowed by the MessageApi I would give it a shot

Comment: DataApi is not for sending messages, so please stop using DataApi for that purpose and instead use MessageApi.